# Managing SaaS Users & Groups via Azure AD SCIM

Tags: azure, identity, scim2

Using Azure AD Premium, 
Enterprise App & SCIM 2.0 Provisioning 
Scope - Only assigned Users & Groups

I'm trying to work through the use case below:

1. SCIM provisioning of users that are assigned to a given AD Group
2. When a user is added it correctly fires off a POST /Users  to Create the User
3. When a user is removed it skips the user a reports - "Details : User details: Skip reason = NotEffectivelyEntitled, Active = True, Assigned = False, Passed scope filter: True;"  But does not send a PATCH or a DELETE to inform the saas app that the user is no longer valid.

So question what is the correct mechanism for using SCIM provisioning to manage only a subset of users in the AD as active users of the system.

e.g. only 1 department in company uses saas app so users list for assigning tickets etc should only be those, and if a user changes departments and no longer has access to the saas app they shouldn't be seen as a valid user of the saas app directory.  The saas licensing will count all registered users so syncing 20,000 users for no reason is not an option.

Seems like SCIM supports this use case with PATCH & DELETE, but Azure AD isn't propagating changes from the users & groups in the enterprise app as expected.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error this issue was with the response objects provided to the POST (create)  - the Username property of the response needs to be the same as the inbound object.

This isn't really documented anywhere for AzureAD SCIM, and the SCIM protocol soesn't specify the values of the properties in response, just the model.   Anyways - much logging and fiddling resulted in the correct GET, POST, PATCH sequence.

This doc is correct, just leaves out any info on the dotted line response requirements.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups#user-provisioning-and-de-provisioning